# Login Authentication in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am trying login authentication but showing an error message. Hope an expert helps me to get the solution.
**This is my HTML code:**

```
<form action="{{url('/')}}/login" method="post">
     @csrf
    <div class="fields">
        <div class="input-field">
            <label for="un" >UserName</label>
            <div class="inpt">
                <input type="text" id="un" placeholder="Enter UserName" required></div>
            </dev>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
         <label for="pw">Password</label>
            <div class="inpt">
                <input type="password" id="pw" placeholder="Enter Your password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rm" >
            <label for="rm">Remember Me</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field-1">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**This is my controller:**

```
public function login():View
{
    return view('login');
}

public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->route('index')
            ->withSuccess('You have successfully logged in!');
    }

    return back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'Your provided credentials do not match our records.',
    ])->onlyInput('email');

}
```

**This is my route(web.php):**

```
Route::get('/login',[Registrationcontroller::class,'login'])->name('login');
Route::post('/authenticate', [Registrationcontroller::class, 'authenticate'])->name('authenticate');
```

**Error:**
The POST method is not supported for route login. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are not showing the opening form tag for that form so we don't know where or how the form is submitted

Comment: lagbox, Now I add this.

Comment: i would assume you intend to submit that form to the `authenticate` route?

Comment: double check your `route` and `form`'s `action` attribute.

Comment: Yes, you are right lagbox

Comment: your input fields do not have a 'name' attribute, btw

Comment: lagbox, I add name attribute and facing same problem. can you suggest me error displaying process  in form with Laravel 10

Answer (score 1):

You should adjust your form's "action" attribute to submit the form to your "authenticate" route:

```
<form action="{{ route('authenticate') }}" method="post">
```

Using the `route` method gives us an absolute URL to a named route.

Comment: lagbox, I did this but It redirect me to login page. if you see my controller I redirect it to index.

Comment: you are not displaying errors in your form so validation or authentication could be failing (which are both redirecting "back", to the login page)

Comment: lagbox ,I delete the success message but it still redirecting login page.

Answer (score 0):

Beware: your `/login` route accepts GET method only, as you can see in your web.php. And that is good because in you login route and controller function u use it for show the view with the login form.
You should make a POST request to `/authenticate` route where your credentials would be validated and, if correct it would redirect you to the index with an authenticated session, otherwise would send you back to the login view.
You should also use the `{{ route('authenticate') }}` function in your form action to make laravel generate the URL the right way.
That being said you should also show the errors on your form, so if there is something going wrong with authentication you would know!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your form action should be pointed to the `/authenticate` endpoint, also you can use named route `{{ route('authenticate') }}`

Your HTML form code should be

```
<form action="{{url('/')}}/authenticate" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="fields">
        <div class="input-field">
            <label for="un" >UserName</label>
            <div class="inpt">
                <input type="text" id="un" placeholder="Enter UserName" required></div>
            </dev>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
         <label for="pw">Password</label>
            <div class="inpt">
                <input type="password" id="pw" placeholder="Enter Your password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rm" >
            <label for="rm">Remember Me</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field-1">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

OR:

```
<form action="{{ route('authenticate') }}" method="post">
     @csrf
    <div class="fields">
        <div class="input-field">
            <label for="un" >UserName</label>
            <div class="inpt">
                <input type="text" id="un" placeholder="Enter UserName" required></div>
            </dev>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
         <label for="pw">Password</label>
            <div class="inpt">
                <input type="password" id="pw" placeholder="Enter Your password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rm" >
            <label for="rm">Remember Me</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field-1">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

*When you use a named route you should be careful if you have any prefix name*